# Nested if else Condition in Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a .rpt file , with a view datasource . I have four parameter which i use in filtering the selection. I have written my selection formula like below.

```
if ({?actype} <> "All") OR ({?actype} <> "All") OR ({?collectorname} <> "All") OR ({?batchno}<> "All") Then
(
if {?actype} <> "All" Then
   {CollectorPerformance.accountType} = {?actype};
if {?collectorname} <> "All" Then 
   {CollectorPerformance.realname} = {?collectorname};
if {?batchno} <> "All" Then 
   {CollectorPerformance.batchno} = {?batchno} 

and
{CollectorPerformance.clientid} = {?clientid}
and 
Date({CollectorPerformance.paymentdate}) >= Date({?from})
and 
Date({CollectorPerformance.paymentdate}) <= Date({?to})

)
```

My issue with the formula, above is that it does not filter by realname and actType. I understand the reason is because the key word "and" is missing . however, it filters the batchno correctly> please how do i make it filter by the remaining two if's ? any help would  appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A selection formula has to be one long valid boolean statement, which is, I think, what you were already suggesting when you say the "and is missing". So in order to fix the first half, you just need to translate those statements into one simplified boolean statement instead of individual statements (those that end in a ';').

```
({?actype}="All" or {?actype}={CollectorPerformance.accountType})
and
({?collectorname}="All" or {?collectorname}={CollectorPerformance.realname})
and
({?batchno}="All" or {?batchno}={CollectorPerformance.batchno})
...
```

For each parameter, a user can either select "All" or enter a specific value to filter by. If "All" is selected, that particular portion of the statement (The part that looks like `{?Parameter}="All"`) will evaluate to `True` and no filtering will be done. Otherwise, only records matching the entered parameter value will return `True`.